# Camera not Rotate with player Player in 360 video recording in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to record 360 video in unity with unity recorder , my camera is child of player ,Camera move correctly but problem is camera dont rotate with player rotation camera rotation still same all the time why
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOb6R.png)

Answer (score 0):

The same issue here, I notice if the stereo is turned on it moves with the orientation.

This fixes the issue but the output resolution is lower.